# Simple combination of riddles!

Tags: riddle, word, cipher, wordplay

> *Embedded in me lies the crucial key,
>
>   don't try too hard to trust all of me.
>
>   interesting, this riddle I hope you find,
>
>   these sentence structures, you must not mind.*
>
> *Heed me not, for I leave very little tracks.
>
>   in a place not far, I have buried them in the past.
>
>   so where oh where, should i start?
>
>   two, the number of steps to solve me thorough.
>
>   off all the places, it can't get more obvious.
>
>   ready yourself, for here comes the hard partt.*
>   **yjcvfqaqwvjkpmqhvjkutkffng**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first letters of each line spell out

> Edit History

This is also hinted at by

> The line "I have buried them in the past"

So if we

> Check the puzzle's edit history, we see that five letters have been changed. Together these spell out "shift".

This points at

> A rot cipher, specifically rot24. This is hinted at by the line "two, the number of steps to solve me thorough" - we're moving every letter two steps backward (or 24 steps forward; they're basically the same thing).

If we use this to decode the last line, we get the final message:

> **What do you think of this riddle?**

Comment: Based on an earlier solution that was accepted but then deleted.